# Barcode generator for small size image

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing

I am using ZXing.net in creating barcodes. I already generated one with the use of the following code:

```
var content = "AAA";
var writer = new BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_93,
    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
    {
        Height = 30,
        Width = 1,
        Margin = 1,
        PureBarcode = true
    }
};
var bitmap = writer.Write(content);
```

Now, I want to resize the barcode to 10cm but ZXing sets minimum size to the barcode depending on the character count of the content.

I tried resizing it through resizing the image file of the barcode but the image became blurry and the scanner can't read it.

Do you have any idea on what library to use that will solve my problem? Or is there any way to resize the barcode to smaller sizes through ZXing.net?

Thank you!

Comment: If this creates a bitmap you should try to increase the dpi of it with setresolution.

Comment: @TaW already tried that but the output is the same. Blurry and not readable by scanner.

Comment: a) show the code b) show the numbers (pixel size and dpi) c) did you write to jpg (not recommended as it will always be blurred when encoding b/w line graphics) or png? d) what do the numbers in the code mean (what are the units) ? - The combination of larger pixel size and large dpi resolution will result in small but crispy images. - Note that 'resizing' the image will never help when you try to enlarge it. You need to resize (enlarge) the output target of the ZXing, not the result it deliverrd!

Comment: @TaW This line helped me `The combination of larger pixel size and large dpi resolution will result in small but crispy images`. Thanks a lot. Post it as an answer so I can mark it as a correct answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quality of the printed result will depend on:

- amount of data (size in pixels)
- resolution of the image (dpi, ie the physical size of each pixel)
- quality of file format

The combination of larger pixel size and large dpi resolution will result in small but crispy images.

You can calculate the amount of data needed to get an image of 2x2 inches minimum of 150dpi as 300x300 pixels. The sizes and resolutions needed and practical will depend on your printer and scanner.

The file format will also help or hurt: JPEG is meant for photographs not for b/w line art as you create. GIF or PNG are recommended.

So: Make the tool create a large enough bitmap and then scale it down to a good resolution (150dpi or better).

You can set the resolution of and image before saving it with `SetResolution(dpix, dpiy)`.